# Print Preview ( Pack does not work )

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, pack

I have a print preview made by `JPanel`, `JDialog` that run error free but doesn't show up after **pack();**.

I know it's a bit long, but you can just **skip to PrintPreview** method, others are just there to know more detail of how I control.

Pls help, I don't know why it doesn't show up on the screen. **Anyone please help thanks so much. ^_^**

```
private PageFormat pf;
private Book pg;
private int pageIndex;
private int totalPages;
private double scaler;

private String title;
private JTextField pageInput;
private JTextField zoomInput;
private PreviewPanel pp;
private JLabel statusBar;
```

**Start Here**

```
public void PrintPreview(String title, Book pg, int pageIndex) {
    this.title = title;
    setTitle(title + " - Print Preview");
    scaler = .5;
    this.pg = pg;
    this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    this.totalPages = pg.getNumberOfPages();
    pf = pg.getPageFormat(pageIndex);
    setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pp = new PreviewPanel();
    add(new JScrollPane(pp), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel topBar = new JPanel();
    topBar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel leftTop = new JPanel();
    JPanel rightTop = new JPanel();
    topBar.add(leftTop, BorderLayout.WEST);
    topBar.add(rightTop, BorderLayout.EAST);

    leftTop.add(new JLabel("Page:"));
    Insets pageButtonInsets = new Insets(0, 2, 0, 2);
    JButton pageBack = new JButton("<");
    pageBack.setMargin(pageButtonInsets);
    pageBack.setActionCommand("back");
    pageBack.addActionListener(this);
    JButton pageForward = new JButton(">");
    pageForward.setMargin(pageButtonInsets);
    pageForward.setActionCommand("forward");
    pageForward.addActionListener(this);
    pageInput = new JTextField(Integer.toString(pageIndex+1));
    pageInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    pageInput.setActionCommand("page");
    pageInput.addActionListener(this);
    leftTop.add(pageBack);
    leftTop.add(pageInput);
    leftTop.add(pageForward);
    rightTop.add(new JLabel("Zoom:"));
    zoomInput = new JTextField((int)(scaler*100)+"%");
    zoomInput.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    rightTop.add(zoomInput);
    JButton zoomSet = new JButton("Set");
    zoomSet.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    zoomSet.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
    rightTop.add(zoomSet);
    zoomSet.setActionCommand("zoom");
    zoomSet.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel lowerBar = new JPanel();
    lowerBar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    lowerBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    statusBar = new JLabel("Ag"); // temporary label for setting size of status bar
    lowerBar.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(lowerBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton license = new JButton("<html>&copy;</html>");
    license.setActionCommand("license");
    license.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    license.addActionListener(this);
    lowerBar.add(license, BorderLayout.WEST);

    JButton print = new JButton("Print...");
    print.setActionCommand("print");
    print.setMargin(new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0));
    print.addActionListener(this);
    lowerBar.add(print, BorderLayout.EAST);
    pack();
    //setVisible(true);
}
```

**End here**

```
private void updateStatusBar() {
    updateStatusBar("Page " + (pageIndex+1) + " of " + totalPages);
}
private void updateStatusBar(String s) {
    updateStatusBar(s, Color.black);
}
private void updateStatusBar(String s, Color c) {
    statusBar.setText(s);
    statusBar.setForeground(c);
}

private void print() {
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    pj.setPageable(pg);
    pj.setJobName(title);
    if (pj.printDialog()) {
        try {
            pj.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Could not print.\nSee the Java error console for details.", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

private class PreviewPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PreviewPanel() {
        resetPreferredSize();
    }

    public void resetPreferredSize() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(pf.getWidth()*scaler), (int)(pf.getHeight()*scaler)));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g1;
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, (int)(pf.getWidth()*scaler), (int)(pf.getHeight()*scaler));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        try {
            g.scale(scaler, scaler);
            pg.getPrintable(pageIndex).print(g, pf, pageIndex);
            updateStatusBar();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ITALIC, 30));
            g.drawString("Page index out of range", 10, 30);
            updateStatusBar("Page index out of range", Color.red);
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.ITALIC, 30));
            g.drawString("Printer error", 10, 30);
            updateStatusBar("Printer error", Color.red);
        }
    }       
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("page")) {
        // change page
        try {
            pageIndex = Integer.parseInt(pageInput.getText())-1;
            pp.repaint();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // do nothing if the entry is not a number
        }
    } else if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("back")) {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            pageIndex--;
            pageInput.setText(Integer.toString(pageIndex+1));
            pp.repaint();
        }
    } else if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("forward")) {
        if (pageIndex < totalPages - 1) {
            pageIndex++;
            pageInput.setText(Integer.toString(pageIndex+1));
            pp.repaint();
        }
    } else if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("zoom")) {
        // change zoom setting
        try {
            scaler = Double.parseDouble(zoomInput.getText().replaceAll("%", ""))// 100.0;
            pp.resetPreferredSize();
            pp.revalidate();
            pp.repaint();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // do nothing if the entry is not a number
        }
    } else if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("license")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, LICENSE);
    } else if (arg0.getActionCommand().equals("print")) {
        print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I figured it out. Hahahaha Actually it does pop out but behind other foreround application....hahahaa finally its done.